# Software updater notifies daily for non-security updates, despite being configured for two weeks

Tags: xubuntu, update-manager

[image: SW updater settings and notification popup]

The update manager pops up daily despite there not being any critical updates and I configured it to display other updates every two weeks.

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
python3-update-manager 1:22.04.10
update-manager 1:22.04.10
update-manager-core 1:22.04.10
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did not express myself unambiguously. There is no security update (see screenshot). I cancel the non-security update, exactly as in the screenshot, but it pops up the next day, and every day, without there ever (well, rarely) being a security update.So because there is no security update, and I set other updates to be displayed every two weeks, it should not come back until two weeks are over, or there is a security update. But it does every day regardless.

Comment: "*The computer also needs to restart to finish installing previous updates*"

Comment: thanks, that's a big egg on my face

Comment: No, that's how humans learn. Be pleased that your skill has grown.